# Does Vue js render data on the webpage only after function is complete?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I was just making a Tic Tac Toe game with **Vuejs** and encountered a little issue.

When a box is clicked on the board, `makeMove()` function is ran which updates the board array which holds the 1's and the -1's for X's and O's on the board respectively.

```
makeMove: function (r, c) {

    if (this.gameOn)
    {
        if (this.board[r][c] == 0) {
            this.board[r].splice(c, 1, this.turn)
            this.turn = this.turn == 1 ? -1 : 1
        }

        if (this.checkGameOver())
            alert ('Someone Won')
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Game is Over')
    }
},
```

But in the `makeMove()` function, after the move is made, I call `checkGameOver()` which checks the board array and displays an alert if game is over.

```
  // Example for just the first row
  checkGameOver: function() {
    let sum = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            sum += this.board[i][j]

        if (sum == 3 || sum == -3) {
            this.gameOn = false
            return true
        }
        sum = 0
    }
}
```

**The problem is that the alert box displays before the last move is rendered on the page. How to fix this issue?**

Answer (score 1):

> Does Vue js render data on the webpage only after function is complete?

Yes. Changing reactive data will not immediately re-render dependent components. Rendering is batched until the start of the next tick.

`alert` pauses execution of your code so, as you say, the function can't complete. However, whether the page updates is a bit more nuanced than that. In Firefox any asynchronous callbacks (including `$nextTick`) can fire while the `alert` is showing, so you should see the page update. In Chrome it pauses everything, even redrawing the page. This behaviour could easily change in the future.

I strongly recommend not using `alert`. For logging purposes use `console.log` and for user feedback implement an HTML/CSS solution instead.

Just getting Vue to update the DOM is not enough, as in Chrome the `alert` will also block the browser from redrawing the page.

To get an `alert` to show in Chrome I had to:

1. Wait for `$nextTick` to ensure the DOM was updated.
2. Wait for `requestAnimationFrame`, which is just before everything gets redrawn.
3. Wait for another `requestAnimationFrame`, which will be after the redraw we want.

I put this into the demo below but, just to be clear, this is nonsense. The correct solution is to stay clear of `alert`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    state: true
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.state = !this.state

      this.$nextTick(() => {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            alert('State is ' + this.state)
          })
        })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="onClick">
    State is {{ state }}
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even used nexttick assure DOM already updated, Not sure that UI has been rendered!